# Get current 1 year from_now as number

Tags: ruby, activesupport

How I can get the next year from now?

```
1.year.from_now
```

I need to get only 2019 as a result from the above code.

Comment: What's wrong with `1.year.from_now.year`?

Answer (score 6):

Use `Time.now.next_year` (activesupport needed) and if you want only year then go with `Time.now.year + 1`

Comment: Upvoting for `Time.now.year + 1` - answers the question, zero dependencies, always works.

Comment: @BartoszPietraszko I agree. Also `Time.now.year.next`

Comment: @iGian thank you very much, I completely forgot about `Integer#next` and never used it in this context before. `Time.now.year.next` hits the spot for me.

Answer (score 4):

Other option

```
require 'date'
Date.today.next_year.year
```

Answer (score 3):

```
1.year.from_now.year
```

does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Any expression returns now + `.next_year` + `.year`

```
Time.now.next_year.year
Date.current.next_year.year
DateTime.current.next_year.year
```

etc. and all others solutions proposed.

I hope it useful for you. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this code: `DateTime.now.year + 1`

Comment: FYI: [When should you use `DateTime` and when should you use `Time`?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#class-DateTime-label-When+should+you+use+DateTime+and+when+should+you+use+Time-3F) (and since you aren't interested in the time part at all, you should probably just use `Date`)